# Shell Script Retokenize Property Values to Keys For All Files In a Directory

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Previously, I wrote a small shell script to "retokenize" a file (useful for comparing for sanity checks). I'm currently in the need of doing something similar for a folder instead of just one file.

I'm curious if there is an easy way to rework the following to be like a method / function and how to recursively pass all files in a folder to the method, so that the end result is that all files in the folder are "retokenized". Hoping to see if there is a quick and easy way to do this. Being doing some googling and playing around, but want to see if anyone here has a quick / easy / clean solution.

**Working version for one file:**

```
#!/bin/bash
date

outputDump="output.txt"
prodPropsFile="input.properties"
prodPropsSortedFile="sorted.properties"
tempPropsFile="temp.properties"

echo "Removing comments and empty lines from prod properties file"
sed '/^#/d' < $prodPropsFile > $tempPropsFile
sed '/^s*$/d' < $tempPropsFile > $prodPropsSortedFile
cp $prodPropsSortedFile $tempPropsFile

echo "Sorting prod properties by value length. So don't do double tokenization"
awk -F"=" '{ st = index($0,"="); print length(substr($0,st+1)),$0 }' $tempPropsFile | sort -rn | cut -d" " -f2- > $prodPropsSortedFile

echo "Retokenizing."
while IFS== read k v;
do
  # Sed escape /, \, and &. Needed for urls like jdbc connections, etc.
  escapedV=$(echo $v | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g; s/\//\\\//g; s/&/\\\&/g')
  # The /gI will replace the tokens globally with case insensitive, this is important in case someone does something like "http://..." versus "HTTP://...".
  sed -i -- "s/$escapedV/$k/gI" $outputDump;
done < "$prodPropsSortedFile"
```

**Example property file:**

```
%%token1%%=value1
%%token2%%=value2
```

**Example input file:**

```
This is a file that has value1 and value2.
```

**Example output file:**

```
This is a file that has %%token1%% and %%token2%%.
```

Comment: @Inian, posted more info as requested. It works for a single file, looking to rework the loop into a method, and pass each file in a folder to that method, so that each file in the folder is update recursively. Hopefully this clarifies the question.

Comment: What if property file has `%%token3%%=value1`? It is not unusual to have more than one key have same value.

Comment: The idea looks good,  but what is stopping to make a function out of this? If I remember right, you want to make a function call which does the actions on each file on the directory?

Comment: Consider running this code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: (I'd also consider implementing with a single pipeline rather than all the temporary files).

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Script that Works for All Files in a Folder on my Mac:**

```
#!/bin/bash
date

retokenize()
{
  echo "Retokenizing $file"
  while IFS== read k v;
  do
    # Sed escape /, \, and &. Needed for urls like jdbc connections, etc.
    escapedV=$(echo $v | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g; s/\//\\\//g; s/&/\\\&/g')
    sed -i '' "s/$escapedV/$k/g" $file;
  done < "$prodPropsSortedFile"
}

# Copy our input to a output file that we will modify, so we don't affect the original.
inputDump="IIQExports"
prodPropsFile="input.properties"
prodPropsSortedFile="sorted.properties"
tempPropsFile="temp.properties"

echo "Removing comments and empty lines from prod properties file"
sed '/^#/d' < $prodPropsFile > $tempPropsFile
sed '/^s*$/d' < $tempPropsFile > $prodPropsSortedFile
cp $prodPropsSortedFile $tempPropsFile

echo "Sorting prod properties by length."
awk -F"=" '{ st = index($0,"="); print length(substr($0,st+1)),$0 }' $tempPropsFile | sort -rn | cut -d" " -f2- > $prodPropsSortedFile

echo "Retokenizing."

find ./$inputDump/ -type f > foo.txt
IFS=$'\n';for file in $(cat foo.txt);
do
  retokenize $file;
done

echo "Done."
date
```

Comment: `for file in $(cat foo.txt)` is a bit of an eyesore. [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- for filenames in particular, the best practice is to save them in a NUL-delimited stream (literal names can contain newlines but not NULs), and to iterate with `while IFS= read -r -d file; do ...`; see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: You might also consider a find/replace approach that doesn't require escaping contents for `sed`; see for example the `gsub_literal` function using `awk` for this purpose given in [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021).

Comment: You might also consider combining multiple `sed` expressions into one invocation. `sed -e '/^#/d' -e '/^s*$/d'`, for example. (BTW, do you mean that latter to delete whitespace? If so, you want `^[[:space:]]*$`; PCRE extensions such as `\s` are not portably available in `sed`).